# Итерация по дочерним GameObject, GetComponentsInChildren - самый быстрый способ?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно получить массив все дочерних и поддочерних объектов конкретного объекта?

К примеру, нужно сменить всем названия, можно конечно функцию рекурсивную использовать, но это имхо костыль, я всегда брал какой-то (любой) компонент и уже по нему обращался к объекту типа:

```
Transform[] children = go.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
```

Есть ли ли способ лучше?

Comment: transform.GetChild(int childIndex).
в цикле проходитесь по всем "детям".
взять количество всех детей transform.ChildCount

Comment: Вам, видимо, совсем лень заглянуть в гугл перед тем, как задать вопрос.

Comment: @Andrey так нужно еще зайти в поддочерние объекты и так до последнего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На удивление, ну ruSO эту тему еще не особо обсудили, так что распишу для будущих вопросов.

---

Связь родитель-потомок в Unity реализована через компонент `Transform` и только через него. Искать детей через другие компоненты - странная затея просто потому что `Transform` **обязательно** прикреплен к **любому** объекту типа `GameObject`.

Для итерации по `Transform`'ам всех потомков путей у нас 2:

1. `GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()`
2. Рекурсивно делать `foreach(var child in this.transform)`

---

Для обоих случаев напишем какой-то универсальный метод, который будет применять переданный метод к каждому потомку:

Для `GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()`

```
void ApplyChildren_GetComponents(GameObject parent, Action<GameObject> action) {
    foreach(Transform child in parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()) {
        action(child.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Для рекурсивного `foreach(var child in this.transform)`

```
void ApplyChildren_Recursive(GameObject parent, Action<GameObject> action) {
    foreach (Transform child in parent.transform) {
        GameObject go = child.gameObject;
        action(go);
        ApplyChildren_Recursive(go, action);
    }
}
```

---

### Результаты

Методы выше кидаем в Update с рандомным методом:

```
void Nothing(GameObject go) {

}

void Update() {
    ApplyChildren_GetComponents(gameObject, Nothing);
    ApplyChildren_Recursive(gameObject, Nothing);
}
```

**Результаты на i7 6700K** для объекта с числом потомков **13824**:

```
| Method                        | Time, ms |
--------------------------------------------
| ApplyChildren_Recursive()     | 24.84    |
| ApplyChildren_GetComponents() | 9.57     |
```

Разница видна невооруженным глазом, и вот почему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лишь чуть меньше половины времени тратиться на нахождение всех `Transform` компонентов через `GetComponentsInChildren`. Да и реализовано это **одним** вызовом к ядру Unity, которое написано на С++.

А вот рекурсивный вызов через C# постоянно будет дергать это ядро, что влечет за собой серьезные накладные расходы.

---

### Вывод

Если нужно получить массив **всех** потомков, потомков потомков  и так далее - лучше использовать `GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы пробежаться по всем потомкам, я бы использовал такую конструкцию:

```
private void ForeachToAllChild(Transform parent, Action<Transform> action)
{
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        action(child);
        if (child.childCount > 0)
            ForeachToAllChild(child, action);
    }
}
```

А вызывать эту функцию можно уже как угодно, пример:

```
ForeachToAllChild(_parentTransform, (Transform child) => {
                if (child.GetComponent<Text>())
                    child.GetComponent<Text>().fontSize = (int)Size.normal;//Size = enum
            });
```

Конечно я посмотрел ответ RiotBr3aker. Но "void ApplyChildren_GetComponents(GameObject parent, Action action)" не перебирает всех потомков. Поэтому он и был быстрее.